# ¿Cómo dirijo toda la salida de un comando a un archivo, tanto la salida normal como los errores?

Tags: linux, unix, línea-de-comandos

Estoy creando un bot en discord que recoge comandos para Linux de entrada, los ejecuta en un servidor, y devuelve la salida y la imprime en el canal de texto.

Para hacer esto estoy utilizando el operador `>` para pasar la salida de un comando a un archivo de texto, para luego imprimirlo.

Por ejemplo:

```
$ cat file.py
print("Hola Mundo")
$ python3 file.py > file.txt
$ cat file.txt
Hola Mundo
$
```

El problema se da al recoger errores, pues el operador `>` no los recoge.

Por ejemplo:

```
$ cat file.py
print("Hola Mundo)
$ python3 file.py > file.txt
$ cat file.txt
```

Aquí no se imprime la salida debido al error

```
    print("Hola Mundo)
                     ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

¿Hay alguna manera de poder guardar también los errores con el operador `>`?

Muchas gracias y saludos :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los mensajes de error se emiten por una salida diferente, llamada "stderr" (standard error) que tiene código 2, mientras que la salida normal "stdout" es la 1. Por ello, debes redirigir la 2 a la 1:

```
comando > fichero_salida 2>&1
```

Una manera más directa es usar `&` para designar a ambos:

```
comando &>fichero_salida
```

En tu caso, `python3 file.py &> file.txt`.

Puedes leer más al respecto de estos descriptores de archivo en sitios como [Descriptores de archivo para stdin, stdout, y stderr](https://blog.carreralinux.com.ar/2017/07/descriptores-de-archivo-stdin-stdout-stderr/).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes redireccionar la salida, por ejemplo, `stderr` y `stdout`:

Suponiendo que mí fichero de prueba contiene `test.py`:

```
print("Error"
```

Ejecuto lo siguiente:

```
$ -> python3 test.py &> error.txt
```

Con esto, tengo la salida del error guardada en el fichero `error.txt`:

```
$ -> cat error.txt 
  File "test.py", line 2
    
                 ^
```

- `1>` : rediriges stdout.
- `2>` : redirigues stderr.
- Con doble `>>` : haces append, por ejemplo `1>>`, `2>`.

Luego tienes más opciones. Tienes más información sobre las salidas en el siguiente enlace [I/O Redirection](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)